# Firebase implementation of order by field and count method

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of schedules with documents with fields like this
[image]
I want to get the route with this highest traffic by running a query that orders by `route` field and do a count of the same field. My question is how can I count after ordering by a field? This is my query right now

```
scheduleByRoutes() {
    return this.afs.collection('schedules', ref => ref.orderBy('route', 'asc')).snapshotChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to count the number of documents of each `route` "category" returned by your orderBy() query.

You should either:

1/ Count them from your client, iterating on the query results.

or

2/ If you know the different routes upfront, issue a query for each `route` and use the [`size()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#size) method of each `QuerySnapshot`. You may use `Promise.all()` to make these calls in parallel.

or

3/ Maintain some counters for each `route` in, for example, another collection. For that you would use a set of Cloud Functions that would update the counters upon Creation/Modification/Deletion.

Be aware that approaches #1 and #2 will cost a document read for each document of the collection. If your collection contains a lot of documents, you may use approach #3.

Comment: Approach #3 sounds like the one I would go with. I need to think about how to do this, let me read up on cloud functions. Never used them, still new to firebase.

Comment: Yes, approach #3 is the most complicated to implement, but probably the most interesting one. Note that you may use some distributed counters if your app has a lot of traffic, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: @Mena Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution? You may accept and upvote my answer if you think it solves your problem?